# Best way to portably assign the result of fgetc() to a char in C

Tags: c, io, type-conversion, portability

Perhaps I'm overthinking this, as it seems like it should be a lot easier.  I want to take a value of type int, such as is returned by fgetc(), and record it in a char buffer if it is not an end-of-file code.  E.g.:

```
char buf;
int c = fgetc(stdin);

if (c < 0) {
    /* handle end-of-file */
} else {
    buf = (char) c;  /* not quite right */
}
```

However, if the platform has signed default chars then the value returned by fgetc() may be outside the range of char, in which case casting or assigning it to (signed) char produces implementation-defined behavior (right?).  Surely, though, there is tons of code out there that does exactly the equivalent of the example.  Is it all relying on implementation-defined behavior and/or assuming 7-bit data?

It looks to me like if I want to be certain that the behavior of my code is defined by C to be what I want, then I need to do something like this:

```
buf = (char) ((c > CHAR_MAX) ? (c - (UCHAR_MAX + 1)) : c);
```

I think that produces defined, correct behavior whether default chars are signed or unsigned, and regardless even of the size of char.  Is that right?  And is it really needful to do that to ensure portability?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fgetc()` returns `unsigned char` and EOF.  EOF is always < 0.  If the system's `char` is `signed` or `unsigned`, it makes no difference.

C11dr 7.21.7.1 2

If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a next character is present, the fgetc function obtains that character as an **unsigned char** converted to an int and advances the associated file position indicator for the stream (if defined).

The concern I have about is that is looks to be 2's compliment dependent and implying the range of `unsigned char` and `char` are both just as wide.  Both of these assumptions are certainly *nearly* always true today.

`buf = (char) ((c > CHAR_MAX) ? (c - (UCHAR_MAX + 1)) : c);`

[Edit per OP comment]
Let's assume `fgetc()` returns no more different characters than stuff-able in the range `CHAR_MIN` to `CHAR_MAX`, then `(c - (UCHAR_MAX + 1))` would be more portable is replaced with `(c - CHAR_MAX + CHAR_MIN)`.  We do not know `(c - (UCHAR_MAX + 1))` is in range when `c is CHAR_MAX + 1`.

A system *could* exist that has a `signed char` range of -127 to +127 and an `unsigned char` range 0 to 255. (5.2.4.2.1), but as `fgetc()` gets a *character*, it seems to have all be `unsigned char` **or** all ready limited itself to the smaller `signed char` range, before converting to `unsigned char` and return that value to the user.  OTOH, if `fgetc()` returned 256 different characters, conversion to a narrow ranged `signed char` would not be portable regardless of formula.

Comment: You are absolutely correct about the nature of fgetc()'s return value, but that wasn't my question.  The crux is that converting an integer value to a signed integer type produces implementation-defined behavior if the value is outside the range of the target type (or please correct me if I'm wrong).  If my platform uses 8-bit signed chars, and the character I read is a British pound sign encoded in ISO-8859-1, then fgetc() will return an int value (positive) 0xA3, which is outside the range of char.  Isn't that a problem?

Comment: In practice, it is not a problem.  Sorting out where the standard says it isn't may take a bit of effort. Every implementation defines the conversion from 0xA3 to `signed char` as a bitwise copy of the lowest 8 bits of the `int` value (and an implementation which did not would probably not be used).

Comment: @chux: upon reflection I think the discussion of character codes vs. signed default chars is a false trail.  As in many places they do, and as C itself does, the docs you quoted conflate "character" and "byte".  The question might better be couched in terms of how multiple fgetc() calls can portably be substituted for one fread() call when the target buffer is of type default char (as may be needed as input to some other function that will treat it as binary data).

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: thanks, I do realize that in practice most, perhaps all platforms of interest will perform the conversion in the way you describe.  I am being anal about portability.  Inasmuch as you and chux seem to agree with my assessment that the behavior of the first example code is implementation-defined, do you agree that my alternative solves that problem, even if perhaps it's overkill?

Comment: For characters returned from `fgets()` that are > `CHAR_MAX`, mapping them to the negative range of `CHAR_MIN` to -1 depends on the integer notation used.  Your solution implies 2's, but would have trouble with 1's compliment, signed magnitude, etc.  Of course these are rarely used today.  If using a 2's compliment machine, the simple `buf = (char) c` would be a portable as your proposed conversion.

Comment: @John Bollinger  To be truly portable, stick with `unsigned char`, but I suspect that leads to other issues down the road.  I do not see using `buf = (char) c` today would introduce some UB with modern machines.  Your post, is not anal, but gets at the core of the foundation of C.

Comment: @chux If you will indulge me just a bit more, can you comment on what the fgetc() specs actually mean?  For example, if I make buf a default char array and do `fgets(buf, 2, stdin)`, then I would like to compare the resulting buf[0] to what I would have gotten from fgetc(stdin).  Is it correct regardless of platform to do `c = (unsigned char) buf[0]` to obtain the latter value from the former?

Comment: @John Bollinger (let's set aside I/O errors and assume EOF was not encountered.)  The comparison of `c = fgetc(stdin)` and `char buf[2]; fgets(buf, 2, stdin); c = (unsigned char) buf[0]` depends on `signed char` to `unsigned char` conversion which is "... the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type." C11dr 6.3.1.3.  If `char` holds as many different values as `unsigned char`, I see no difference.

Comment: @John Bollinger  If such `int` to `char` conversions are potentially problematic, recommend using a global macro (or function).  But all-in-all, I see other portability issues much more a concern that does `buf = (char) c` _always_ work.

Answer (score 4):

Practically, it's simple - the obvious cast to `char` always works.
But you're asking about portability...

I can't see how a real portable solution could work.
This is because the guaranteed range of `char` is -127 to 127, which is only 255 different values. So how could you translate the 256 possible return values of `fgetc` (excluding `EOF`), to a `char`, without losing information?

The best I can think of is to use `unsigned char` and avoid `char`.

Answer (score 2):

With thanks to those who responded, and having now read relevant portions of the C99 standard, I have come to agree with the somewhat surprising conclusion that storing an arbitrary non-EOF value returned by `fgetc()` as type `char` without loss of fidelity is not guaranteed to be possible.  In large part, that arises from the possibility that `char` cannot represent as many distinct values as `unsigned char`.

For their part, the stdio functions guarantee that if data are written to a (binary) stream and subsequently read back, then the read back data will compare equal to the original data.  That turns out to have much narrower implications than I at first thought, but it does mean that `fputs()` must output a distinct value for each distinct `char` it successfully outputs, and that whatever conversion `fgets()` applies to store input bytes as type `char` must accurately reverse the conversion, if any, by which `fputs()` would produce the input byte as its output.  As far as I can tell, however, `fputs()` and `fgets()` are permitted to fail on any input they don't like, so it is not certain that fputs() maps every possible `char` value to an `unsigned char`.

Moreover, although `fputs()` and `fgets()` operate as if by performing sequences of `fputc()` and `fgetc()` calls, respectively, it is not specified what conversions they might perform between `char` values in memory and the underlying `unsigned char` values on the stream.  **If** a platform's `fputs()` uses standard integer conversion for that purpose, however, then the correct back-conversion is as I proposed:

```
int c = fgetc(stream);
char buf;

if (c >= 0) buf = (char) ((c > CHAR_MAX) ? (c - (UCHAR_MAX + 1)) : c);
```

That arises directly from the integer conversion rules, which specify that integer values are converted to unsigned types by adding or subtracting the integer multiple of <target type>_MAX + 1 needed to bring the result into the range of the target type, supported by the constraints on representation of integer types.  Its correctness for that purpose does not depend on the specific representation of `char` values or on whether `char` is treated as signed or unsigned.

However, if  `char` cannot represent as many distinct values as `unsigned char`, or if there are `char` values that `fgets()` refuses to output (e.g. negative ones), then there are possible values of `c` that could not have resulted from a `char` conversion in the first place.  No back-conversion argument is applicable to such bytes, and there may not even be a meaningful sense of `char` values corresponding to them.  In any case, whether the given conversion is the correct reverse-conversion for data written by `fputs()` seems to be implementation defined.  It is certainly implementation-defined whether `buf = (char) c` will have the same effect, though it does have on very many systems.

Overall, I am struck by just how many details of C I/O behavior are implementation defined.  That was an eye-opener for me.

Comment: Is there anything in the C standard that would force a one's complement or sign/magnitude C implementation to choose unsigned for their default `char`?  e.g. some requirement that a `char` be able to represent every possible byte (assuming 8-bit `char`)?  If so, that would close this apparent loophole.  If not, then such an actively-hostile C implementation would perhaps be legal, but not good.  i.e. the implementation-defined behaviour should be chosen so that this works right for a C implementation to be useful!  (I wish C would standardize more stuff, like arithmetic shifts...)

Comment: @PeterCordes, no, the standard places no such limitation on implementations' choices.  With respect to this matter, it says only "[The implementation shall define char to have the same range, representation, and behavior as either signed char or unsigned char](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p15)."  In practice, however, although the standard does not *require* it, I'd consider it a quality-of-implementation issue that implementations should comply with the rule you suggest.

Comment: I meant it might *indirectly* end up placing that requirement.  i.e. maybe there's a rule somewhere else that can't be satisfied if `char` is signed one's complement.

Comment: @PeterCordes, your question is by nature difficult to answer with certainty.  I'm now a lot more familiar with the standard than I was when I originally posed the question and posted this answer, however, and I am fairly confident that there is no combination of provisions that have the effect you describe.

Comment: That's too bad, and thanks for the reply.  It would be nice if such diabolical C implementations weren't allowed, so we could stop agonizing over being *truly* portable when we (think we) know that no reasonable modern C implementation would be like this, for modern or potential future hardware.  Learning Rust is on my to-do list; I like their idea of making 2's complement overflow allowed only if specifically requested ([`foo.wrapping_add(0x1234)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.wrapping_add)), and overflow-detection, and built-in integer functions including popcnt.

Answer (score 2):

> Best way to portably assign the result of fgetc() to a char in C

**C2X is on the way**

A sub-problem is saving an `unsigned char` value into a `char`, which may be *signed*.  With 2's complement, that is not a problem.<sup>*1</sup>

On non-2's complement machines with *signed* `char` that do not support -0 <sup>*2</sup>, that is a problem.  (I know of no such machines.)

In any case, with [C2X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C2x), support for non-2's complement encoding is planned to be dropped, so as time goes on, we can *eventually* ignore non-2's complement issues and confidently use

```
int c = fgetc(stdin);
... 
char buf = (c > CHAR_MAX) ? (char)(c - (UCHAR_MAX + 1)) : (char)c;
```

---

**`UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`??**

A 2nd portability issue not discussed is when `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`.  e.g. All integer types are 64-bit.  Some graphics processor have used a common size for all integer types.

On such unicorn machines, `if (c < 0)` is insufficient.  Could use:

```
int c = fgetc(stdin);

#if UCHAR_MAX <= INT_MAX
  if (c < 0) {
#else 
  if (c == EOF && (feof(stdin) || ferror(stdin))) {
#endif
...
```

Pedantically, `ferror(stdin)` could be true due to a prior input function and not this one which returned `UCHAR_MAX`, but let us not go into that [rabbit-hole](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rabbit_hole).

---

<sup>*1</sup> In the case of `int` to *signed* `char` with `c > CHAR_MAX`, "Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised." applies.  With 2's complement, this is *overwhelmingly* maps [128 255] to [-128 -1].

<sup>*2</sup> With non-2's compliment and -0 support, the common mapping is *least 8 bits* remain the same.  This does make for 2 zeros, yet properly handling of *strings* in `<string.h>` uses "For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value)." So -0 is not a *null character* as that char is accessed as a non-zero `unsigned char`.